# How do you reference an object interface's key in its value using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm trying to create an object interface (transforms), that has keys which are properties of a generic object (T), so that the keys can map to a function that passes the property value of T specific to the key it was passed.

```
interface Options<T> {
  headers: (keyof T)[]
  filename: string
  items: T[]
  transforms?: Partial<{
    [field in T as keyof T]: (item: T[field extends keyof T ? field : never]) => string
  }>
}
```

As of now, item always resolves to never. I want it to be able to resolve to T[field] or rather T[keyof T] specific to the key it's attached to.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a better example of what I was trying to accomplish. I'm trying to make sure that the arguments passed to the functions in the transforms object, which have keys that are properties of T, have the correct type (T[keyof T]). In the corrected example below, color should be a string, and isTasty should be a boolean when passed as arguments in "transforms".

```
interface Food {
  isTasty: boolean
  color: string
}

interface Options<T> {
  headers: (keyof T)[]
  filename: string
  items: T[]
  transforms?: Partial<{
    ?
  }>
}

function Foo<T>({headers, filename, items, transforms}: Options<T>){
  return 'bar'
}

Foo({
  headers: ['isTasty', 'color'],
  filename: 'test',
  items: [{color: 'red', isTasty: true}] as Food[],
  transforms: {
    color: (color) => '#' + color,
    isTasty: (isTasty) => isTasty ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  }
})
```

[fixed and working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0BNkG8CwAUMssAM4AqcZYAngFzIBGmANhHCESQuq%20lEY0ooAOZEAvkSKhIsRCgDyABzDB0IMgB4KAPjzdkACw5ZoZRgAoA1hFroYyCgEoA2gF1DMYOxBwAthBCYCIg4sSkkP4WTh6GIZxkMALRAPyMAApwUGpwrFoEESSu3hCsOKDItvaOFO5WylDoytB0jBQlwGVY7s7IALz6wmKGErqS0oQwAK4gCGoaaJg6upa4JnBmUGQANMjevgEQe8BRu8gJmslQ0RKMKguaK86FJFAQYNNQIMgA5EzZX4TQhEDDoNaGDZbGKuX7kKg0Wi-Pa-Xj8KC-dw7Lw%20CB%20QKMX6QGjIwynCDRRiuXBogSE95YZGkSjUNoXKDTCASdzIahLbAebERS5JFIxV4kZC0wTISzSvqDP4AYl%20yAA1FK%20AIhZLmQi2ZZ4azaAr9EbEchUn8AJoQMiqwkAOXQQIiUkIEmcQA)

Comment: My guess is that you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp9agW), but without a [mre] that includes at least one use case showing an input and expected output, I'm not sure.  Can you [edit] such an example into your code?

Comment: Actually that's perfect. I'm not sure how I ended up making this overcomplicated. 

Comment: Note that there's quite a bit wrong about `[field in T as keyof T]: (item: T[field extends keyof T ? field : never]) => string`, to the extent where I doubt it's worth explaining.  Suffice it to say that it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It's great that my suggestion works for you.  For the sake of making this a good Stack Overflow question for future readers, could you still [edit] the question to make it clear what you're looking for?  Like, have an example `interface Foo {a: string, b: number, c: boolean}` and then you want `Options<Foo>` to have a `transforms` property of type `{a: (item: string) => string; b: (item: number) => string; c: (item: boolean) => string;}`.  Or any concrete use case that helps to express your intent

Comment: Edited the question! Hopefully thats more clear.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance, but note that conventionally type parameters are written with UpperPascalCase names (usually single letters); you've written `[field in XXX]: YYY` but that `field` is a type parameter, not a key name.  It should be `[Field in XXX]: YYY` or even more conventionally `{[K in XXX]: YYY}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the `transforms` property to be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T`.  Writing `{[K in keyof T]: F<K>}` will produce a new type with the same keys as `T` but whose properties are `F<K>` for each key type `K`.  In your case, you want each property to be a function that accepts a value of the type corresponding to the property value of `T` at the key `K`.  That is, a function that accepts a value of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`.  Like so:

```
{ [K in keyof T]: (property: T[K]) => string }
```

Note that if you want to apply [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to it, you can write this more simply with the [optional mapping modifier (`?`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
{ [K in keyof T]?: (property: T[K]) => string }
```

That gives you the following definition for `Options<T>`:

```
interface Options<T> {
  headers: (keyof T)[]
  filename: string
  items: T[]
  transforms?: {
    [K in keyof T]?: (property: T[K]) => string
  }
}
```

And then everything works as you want:

```
function foo<T>(o: Options<T>) { }

foo({
  headers: ['isTasty', 'color'],
  filename: 'test',
  items: [{ color: 'red', isTasty: true }],
  transforms: {
    color: (color) => '#' + color,
    isTasty: (isTasty) => isTasty ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AKgHzIDeAsAFDLIAWEcAJtHgFzIAUA1hAJ7YYyIgEoA2gF0adGMAA2EEHAC2ETnjBRQAcxnJgkFRxFT9WuPhjYoxgPycqtOsnEBpAyGR9BwopIdudChsdGgwfk4id0lRZABeMk1tED1nAF8aTOoaGABXEAQsXGRrbGISLmxODGL8CrjyZGzc7GwuJzpGFjZOcQByYDwiOE1+foAaZH6EbHkbfskJ-TlFZTVOfshNSf1DCGM+ptn5qE2oCGZJg2HRiM4tPJR0pfMoSzxrWxNOlxObThcf5QOKJaYAYn6yAA1MhgctnHQhiMxoDkXd+KCyOixsg7NMAJoQPBQzYAOWw-X02XSoiAA)